Is this the difference between an efficiency apartment and a studio apartment?
According to my dictionary (Oxford latest edition),
an efficiency apartment has a room which is the kitchen, bedroom and the living room at the same time and in addition to that an efficiency apartment has a separate bathroom.
An studio apartment has a room that is the bedroom and the living room at the same time. It also has a separate kitchenette and a separate bathroom.

What you describe as "an efficiency apartment" sounds like what we would call in the UK a bedsit. I know you're quoting the Oxford dictionary (I assume OED) but this sounds US to me.

@timchessish - It does seem to be a US term; Collins Dictionary specifically says so.  The difference between a 'studio apartment' and an 'efficiency apartment' is that of size.  Efficiency apartments tend to be much smaller than studios, and have more basic kitchen arrangements.

There's no difference.  The term seems to have arisen between 1900 and 1930 in response to rising populations on the East and West coasts of the USA as a way to describe a room which was somewhat like a hotel room, but had basic self catering facilities.  It was "efficient" in the sense that unlike a hotel room, you could prepare your own food, rather than be forced to eat at the hotel restaurant.  They often featured such "efficiencies" as a "Murphy bed" that could fold against the wall and other furnishings.
In the 20th century the two terms were both in use. But in the 21st century, the term "studio" has become more common, so "efficiency apartment" sounds slightly dated.

One US housing-related website I've seen says that 'efficiency apartments' are much smaller than studios, as if the term has been revived with a newer meaning. 'An efficiency apartment is an apartment with all the living spaces contained within one room and is usually less than 500 square feet. These apartments lack space and amenities but are located in desirable areas and are well-suited for people looking to live alone in heavily populated cities. '
